# Where can I purchase ספר הבית היהודי volume 7 by Rabbi Aaron Zachai?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

It is out of print and Lehmann's (the UK's main sefarim distributor) doesn't have it and can't get hold of it. I don't mind if I have to buy the whole set, but one way or another I would like to own a physical copy of volume 7

Does anyone know where I can buy it?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a UK-source?

Comment: @Dov yes ideally UK source, thanks for answering, I'll use those as a backup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you are looking specifically for a UK source? But it is definitely purchasable in Israel.

For example this site [here](https://www.sefer.org.il/items/3731272-%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%99-%D7%99-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D) and [here](https://www.hbooks.co.il/product/%D7%94%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99---10-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D--%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%99) has all 10 chalokim.

It would also seem to be purchasable in the US as well - see [here](https://seforimcenter.com/Rabbi-Aharon-Zakai/HaBayit-HaYehudi--Rabbi-Aharon-Zakai-10-vol.__p-615-7075.aspx) and [here](https://www.sephardicwarehouse.com/collections/sifrei-rebbi-aharon-zakai/products/habayit-hayehudi-10-volumes) to name a couple.

If you are looking for UK sources alone - I would try the following:

1. Contact Lehmann's and place an order - they receive regular shipments from Israel and so you can ask them if they can source it for you.
2. Contact other seforim stores e.g. [Torah Treasures](https://www.torahtreasures.co.uk/), [Aisenthal's](https://aisenthaljudaica.com/products/books/), [Chaim's bookstore](https://www.google.com/maps/uv?pb=!1s0x48761098101df057%3A0x4e3f260e7f0e9be!3m1!7e115!4s%2Fmaps%2Fplace%2Fchaim%2Bbookstore%2F%4051.5774298%2C-0.1994208%2C3a%2C75y%2C191.55h%2C90t%2Fdata%3D*213m4*211e1*213m2*211sJ9QRDaflwqqkBHq2uPoxVg*212e0*214m2*213m1*211s0x48761098101df057%3A0x4e3f260e7f0e9be%3Fsa%3DX!5schaim%20bookstore%20-%20Google%20Search!15sCgIgAQ&imagekey=!1e2!2sJ9QRDaflwqqkBHq2uPoxVg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjH64z3kO39AhUZWcAKHYBhChEQpx96BAh3EA0) etc.

Comment: Still haven't been able to source from any of these.

Comment: Did you call Lehmann's? They would normally order in from Eretz Yisroel specially.

Comment: Well I asked my supplier to ask them on my behalf but no luck. 6 months of time has elapsed, I can't believe it. I need to get on with this. Life is so short!

Comment: I would call them direct - +44(0)191 430 0555 or email weborders@lehmanns.co.uk